# How to reliably detect BLE device is out of range to properly disconnect and then reconnect it?

Tags: c#, wpf, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm writing a WPF app communicating with a finger sensor over BLE. Generally it works just fine: I can scan for sensors, select one, connect, disconnect, etc. However there is one issue remaining. When the sensor is out of range, the app stops receiving value changed notifications, which are normally coming every 10 milliseconds. If I try to disconnect it manually a few seconds later with this code:

```
var result = await SelectedCharacteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.None);
if (result == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
{
    RemoveValueChangedHandler();
    res = true;
    NotifyUser("Successfully disconnected from the selected BerryMed sensor.", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
}
else
{
    NotifyUser("Error un-registering for value changed notifications.", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
}
```

the result returns false. Again it happens only when the app stops receiving notification due to out of range and my response is delayed for a few seconds.

So is there any way to programmatically detect the loss of connection (when notifications stop coming) and then call this method to disconnect on time?

I tried using a special 500-ms timer to watch for value changed notifications and detect when they stop coming. It takes 1 second to detect it and call disconnect. But the problem is that disconnection works only once. If I connect again without quitting the app and get out of range again, then this disconnect does not work again. If I restart the app, it repeats - success on disconnection after the first out of range and failure on the subsequent.

Comment: BluetoothLEDevice class (IBluetoothLEDevice interface) has ConnectionStatusChanged event handler. This is the way [Bluetooth Framework](https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm) detects when BLE device disconnects.

Answer (score 2):

That is not the proper way to disconnect.
The result from your method returns false because you can not write to a device when it is out of reach, so this result is expected.
Use the ConnectionStatusChanged event handler to find find out if a connection is lost.
Use the result of this event to disconnect.
The way to do that on Windows is to dispose of all references to a BluetoothLEDevice object for a device (and if no other app on the system has a reference to the device) will trigger an automatic disconnect after a small timeout period. Just call :
    bluetoothLeDevice.Dispose();

If You want to reconnect, use the advertisement watcher to see if the device is ready to reconnect and in reach again. Your device also has a disconnected timeout that can vary from a few seconds up to 40 seconds, after that time it will start advertising again.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and finally got it working as expected. So my issue is resolved. Thanks to GrooverFromHolland.